# cannot upload .xls in epplus in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, epplus

I got this code to upload an excel file and put it in gridview :

```
protected void save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string filename = Path.GetFileName(excelfileupload.FileName);
            excelfileupload.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Uploader/") + filename);
            err.Text = "Upload status: File uploaded!";
            DataTable dt = getDataTableFromExcel(Server.MapPath("~/Uploader/") + filename);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            err.Text = "Upload status: The file could not be uploaded. The following error occured: " + ex.Message;
        }
    }

    private DataTable getDataTableFromExcel(string path)
    { 
        using (var pck = new OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage())
        {
            using (var stream = File.OpenRead(path))
            {
                pck.Load(stream);
            }
            var ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.First();
            DataTable tbl = new DataTable();

            bool hasHeader = true; 
            foreach (var firstRowCell in ws.Cells[1, 1, 1, ws.Dimension.End.Column])
            {
                tbl.Columns.Add(hasHeader ? firstRowCell.Text : string.Format("Column {0}", firstRowCell.Start.Column));
            }
            var startRow = hasHeader ? 2 : 1;
            for (var rowNum = startRow; rowNum <= ws.Dimension.End.Row; rowNum++)
            {
                var wsRow = ws.Cells[rowNum, 1, rowNum, ws.Dimension.End.Column];
                var row = tbl.NewRow();
                foreach (var cell in wsRow)
                {
                    row[cell.Start.Column - 1] = cell.Text;
                }
                tbl.Rows.Add(row);
            }
            return tbl;
        }
    }
```

every thing work ok but when uploading a file .xls it gave me an error :

```
Upload status: The file could not be uploaded. The following error occured: Can not open the package. Package is an OLE compound document. If this is an encrypted package, please supply the password
```

don't know what its mean but when try to convert it into .xlsx its work fine with no error

how to solve it ?

Comment: Did you even read what EPPlus is? *EPPlus is a .net library that reads and writes Excel 2007/2010 files using the Open Office Xml format (xlsx).*

Comment: yes i know and work on it but i do an asp.net code to upload a file came from fingerprint device and gave me that error

Answer (score 0):

> how to solve it ?

Don't use XLS files or don't use EPPlus.

> ## [Create advanced Excel 2007/2010 spreadsheets on the server](http://epplus.codeplex.com/)
>
> EPPlus is a .net library that reads and writes **Excel 2007/2010 files using the Open Office Xml format (xlsx)**

If you need to open an XLS file [use JET or ACE](http://www.connectionstrings.com/excel/).